# T-SQL query relative week numbering issue when turning the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this view that has a specific, relative week numbering column called WeekNr. The two columns (WeekNr and CURWEEK) in the source table are held with the usual calendar week numbering: 1, 2, 3... to 52.
This view is used in an Excel file, and business wants to see a relative week numbering from -12 to +6: the past 12 weeks and 6 weeks projection, relative to week Zero which is the Current Week (today, 13 January 2015, this is calendar week 2).
So, this code worked just fine, up until the year turned. After 52, the WeekNr - CURWEEK doesn't work anymore as wished. 
 
**Do you have some kind of elegant solution for this?**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_NOSSCE_HealthKPIs_DEV]
 AS 
 (
SELECT 
[Region]
      ,[Country]
      ,[GlobalMaterialCode]
      ,[Material]
      ,[MaterialCode]
      ,[PlantCode]
      ,[Plant]
      ,[Brand]
      ,
      (WeekNr - (SELECT TOP 1 CURWEEK FROM [TO_BDB].[dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_FACT_NORMALIZED]) ) as 
      WeekNr 
      ,[MEDICAL_NEED]
      ,[TOP_SELLER]
      ,[PHARMABU_CODE]
      ,[PharmaBU]
      ,[SourceLocationCode]
      ,[SourceLocation]
      ,[InventoryTotal]
      ,[MaxStockQtyTotal]
      ,[TotalSafetyStockTotal]
      ,[DangerTreshold]
      ,[FORECAST_FLG]
      ,[DangerZoneDesc]
 FROM [TO_BDB].[dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_PAST12_HIST] 
 WHERE (WeekNr - (SELECT TOP 1 CURWEEK
 FROM [TO_BDB].[dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_FACT_NORMALIZED]) )
  BETWEEN -12 and 6
  GROUP BY [Region]
      ,[Country]
      ,[GlobalMaterialCode]
      ,[Material]
      ,[MaterialCode]
      ,[PlantCode]
      ,[Plant]
      ,[Brand]
,WeekNr, [MEDICAL_NEED]
      ,[TOP_SELLER]
      ,[PHARMABU_CODE]
      ,[PharmaBU]
      ,[SourceLocationCode]
      ,[SourceLocation]
      ,[InventoryTotal]
      ,[MaxStockQtyTotal]
      ,[TotalSafetyStockTotal]
      ,[DangerTreshold]
      ,[FORECAST_FLG]
      ,[DangerZoneDesc]
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_NOSSCE_HealthKPIs] WHERE WeekNr > 0
)
```

UPDATE, I created the Calendar table, why does it give me a Week 53?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_CALENDAR](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR]  AS (datepart(year,[DATE])) PERSISTED,
    [SEMESTER]  AS (case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(7) then '1' else '2' end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [TRIMESTER]  AS (case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(4) then '1' else case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(7) then '2' else case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(10) then '3' else '4' end end end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [MONTH]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),0))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),0) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),0) end) PERSISTED,
    [WEEK]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(week,[DATE]),0))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(week,[DATE]),0) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(week,[DATE]),0) end),
    [DAY]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),0))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),0) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),0) end) PERSISTED,
    [WEEKNUMBER]  AS (datepart(week,[DATE])),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: I would say something along the lines of (WeekNr - CURWEEK + 52) % 52, that's what I use for calculating angle differences nearing 0 or 360, which I think has the same problems you are having.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some sample data on how it looks now with regards to the week ? It would help to see how it looks when solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're using code to generate an Excel file, it might be better to do the relative numbering with Excel formulas rather than using SQL.

Second, week numbers don't identify weeks. To identify a week, you need both the year and the week number, or you need a date. That means you might need to change a table to store the year in addition to the week.

Here we use a calendar table to simplify queries like this one. A minimal, simplified calendar table might look like this. We use ISO years and weeks, but don't let that confuse you. You can use just about any kind of numbering you want. (Written for PostgreSQL, but the principles are the same for SQL Server.)

```
create table calendar (
  cal_date date primary key,
  iso_year integer not null,
  iso_week integer not null
);

create index on calendar (iso_year, iso_week);
```

We use check constraints (not shown) to guarantee that the values for iso_year and iso_week are right for every value of cal_date. Very few (highly trusted) people have privileges to insert and delete rows.

In standard SQL, I might write something like this to get the absolute weeks we're interested in.

```
select distinct iso_year, iso_week
from calendar
where cal_date between cast(current_date - interval '12 weeks' as date) 
                   and cast(current_date + interval  '6 weeks' as date) 
order by iso_year, iso_week;
```

```
iso_year  iso_week
2014      43
2014      44
2014      45
...
2015      7
2015      8
2015      9
```

It returns 19 rows, which seems to be the right number for your case.  (Watch for off-by-one mistakes on my part.)  Put that into a common table expression or a view, and you can number the relative weeks with simple arithmetic. (I used CTEs so this answer is more or less self-contained.)

```
with absolute_weeks as (
  select distinct iso_year, iso_week
  from calendar
  where cal_date between cast(current_date - interval '12 weeks' as date) 
                     and cast(current_date + interval  '6 weeks' as date) 
)
select *, (row_number() over (order by iso_year, iso_week) - 13) as relative_week
from absolute_weeks 
order by iso_year, iso_week;
```

```
iso_year  iso_week  relative_week
--
2014      43        -12
2014      44        -11
2014      45        -10
...
2015      7           4
2015      8           5
2015      9           6
```

If your data contains the year and the week, you can just join your query to this on iso_year and iso_week. If your data has the date instead, you can move the previous query into a CTE or a view, and join the calendar table to get the dates for each week.

```
with absolute_weeks as (
  select distinct iso_year, iso_week
  from calendar
  where cal_date between cast(current_date - interval '12 weeks' as date) 
                     and cast(current_date + interval  '6 weeks' as date) 
), relative_weeks as (
  select *, (row_number() over (order by iso_year, iso_week) - 13) as relative_week
  from absolute_weeks 
)
select c.cal_date, c.iso_year, c.iso_week, r.relative_week
from calendar c
inner join relative_weeks r on c.iso_year = r.iso_year and c.iso_week = r.iso_week
order by c.cal_date;
```

```
cal_date    iso_year  iso_week  relative_week
--
2014-10-20  2014      43        -12
2014-10-21  2014      43        -12
2014-10-22  2014      43        -12
...
2015-01-12  2015       3          0
2015-01-13  2015       3          0
2015-01-14  2015       3          0
...
2015-02-27  2015       9          6
2015-02-28  2015       9          6
2015-03-01  2015       9          6
```

The current week--the week of 2015-01-13--is ISO week 3, not week 2 as you number them. Your own calendar table should reflect your own logic, not mine.

This query returns 133 rows, which seems to be the right number. Every ISO week has seven days, so 7 * 19 rows is the right number for a calendar table based on ISO weeks. Your own requirements might give you an occasional week that has a different number of days.

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for the contribution. It would be good to pass this to the Excel part but it's not possible at the moment.
The solution with the CTE looks good, although I don't have the calendar date available. I only have an nvarchar(32) string in the raw data table named CURWEEK and CALWEEK, ex. '02.2015' . I think I will use the GETDATE() as a cal_date, if my understanding is correct, the CURRENT week, from Monday to Sunday, equals to the week number that comes from GETDATE().

Comment: You can build expressions like '02.2015' on the fly from a calendar table. (Or store them, along with suitable check constraints, *in* a calendar table.) For SQL Server, adding the expression `right('00'+ convert(varchar, iso_week),2)  + '.' + cast(iso_year as varchar)` to "absolute_weeks" should give you a column you can join on.

Comment: I have a CALENDAR table, can you tell me why does it give me a week 53?
I update the code above with this table structure.

Comment: You (I) have a week 53, because `52 * 7 = 364`. Every year is longer than 364 days. Your company might have a rule that week 52 is the last week of every year, and that week 52 might have more than 7 days. It might have some other kind of rule. In any case, your own calendar table should reflect your own company's logic. ([ISO weeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) are based on different logic.)

Comment: Does this mean I cannot create the table with calculated columns because they are not ISO? My company also uses 52 weeks only, no matter what.

Comment: I'm going to create a new topic with this last question... Thanks Mike for the patience and help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969319/t-sql-calculated-column-how-to-get-iso-week-number

Comment: @KatalinPap: It doesn't mean you cannot create the table with calculated columns because they're  not ISO. It just means your check constraints will probably be a little more complex.  Some companies don't use check constraints at all--they just load the calendar table from a spreadsheet and revoke insert, update, and delete permissions from (almost) everybody.